# Google PubSub how to process seeked messages whilst streaming-pull messages

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to process messages returned by `seek(timestamp)` in Python.

I am subscribed to non-seek messages using streaming pull:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)
future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback())

with subscriber:
    try:
        future.result()
    except TimeoutError:
        future.cancel()

def callback(msg):
    msg.ack()
```

I found the `SeekRequest` object:

https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/2.4.0/types.html

I was expecting `seek()` to cause the replayed messages to be received by streaming pull again. However, instead there's a `SeekResponse` object.

Is it possible to divert the seeked messages to arrive via the streaming pull callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seek response does not contain any messages. In fact, it is an empty response. The RPC has a response so you can know if the seek had any errors such as being performed on a subscription that doesn't exist. Seek causes the replayed messages to be redelivered to subscribers as messages along the same path as regular delivery, e.g., receiving them via streaming pull again.

Comment: May i ask, what format is the seek() timestamp argument in Python? String, UTC integer? The API just says "Timestamp" and i cannot find any example. Not sure what I actually need to pass in.